# Would str_replace work, and how?

Tags: php, replace, echo, str-replace, fread

I'm trying to read up on str_replace but I can't get anything to work. I have this code, that works just fine (text file contains: track - artist) as long as there is no " ' " in the track or artist names, and that's pretty common :)
Replacing it with " - " in the output, should work (I'm hoping) but how?

```
<?php
    $file = "lyrics.txt";

    if (0 < filesize($file)) {
        $myfile = fopen("lyrics.txt", "r") or die("Splat!");
        echo "<a href='https://www.musixmatch.com/search/";
        echo fread($myfile,filesize("lyrics.txt"));
        echo "'target='_blank'><span title='Search lyrics' class='button'>Musixmatch</span> <a/>";
        fclose($myfile);
    }
?>
```

Comment: you should indent your code, makes it easier to read :)

Comment: it looks indent from here or maybe you posted before I re-re-re-re-edited the post? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) expects the search string, the replacement string and the string to work on and *returns a new string with the replaced values* (which might have been your issue).

It's as easy as that:

```
<?php
$input = "some 'foo' with 'bar'";
$input = str_replace("'", "-", $input);
echo $input;
?>
```

Prints:

```
some -foo- with -bar-
```

([PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/89914cd470b3b178b056bde698af0e3d27d04843))

Comment: I will have to read more about this apparently cause I don't get it to work nevertheless :/
I'm confident though that the solution lies in your answer @marvin. I'm just to stupid to understand it for now :D

Comment: Maybe next time include your failed attempt(s) so we can be more specific as well ;)